# Accessing members of derived classes

Tags: c++

I have a base class and a class derived from it. In the example below, `Frame_Pic` is a derived class of `Base_Pic`, the details of which I have not included. `Frame_Pic` has members, `vertical`,`horizontal`, and `corners` which is not in the base class. `Picture` is an interface class and basically holds a pointer to `Base_Pic`.

When I try to assign new values to these in the `reframe` function below, I get an error stating that `Base_Pic` has no such data members.

The action, `pic.p->vertical`, will think I am accessing the base class. If I put these data members in the base class, the rest of my functions are written in a way that it will not accommodate this addition. How can I assign to these data members?

```
Picture frame(const Picture& pic, char v, char c, char h)
{
    Frame_Pic* temp = new Frame_Pic(pic.p);
    temp->vertical = v;
    temp->horizontal = h;
    temp->corners = c;
    Picture temp2(temp);
    return temp2;
}

void reframe(Picture& pic, char v, char c, char h)
{
    pic.p->vertical = v;
    pic.p->horizontal = h;
    pic.p->corners = c;
}
```

Comment: Is Picture your Base_Pic or Frame_Pic class?

Comment: Can you post the actual error message? And show us how you initialize the objects that you send to the function.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, trying to access members in Frame_Pic through a pointer (or reference) to Base_Pic?

Comment: @NonlinearIdeas - see this line in the question - "Picture is an interface class and basically holds a pointer to Base_Pic."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to set items of a derived class while feeding a function a pointer to the base type.  The way to do this is to create a virtual function in the base class and implement it in the derived class.

for instance...

```
virtual void BaseClass::SetupSomeStuff(...) {
}

void DerivedClass::SetupSomeStuff(...) {
your assignments here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing them directly, use your Picture interface to declare set and get methods (assuming both are needed) for those members, and implement them in the derived class.

Direct access to member variables does not behave polymorphically, hence your error.

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink the way you wrote the functions and how the classes interact in general.
Reframe might be a function member of `Frame_Pic` but its functionality has nothing to do with any instance of the class `Frame_Pic`. In fact, since all you can know for sure is that `Picture` holds a pointer to a `Base_pic`, it might as well hold a pointer to an instance of a different class that derives `Base_pic` that does not define members named vertical, horizontal or corners.

You should instead create a new `Frame_pic` instance like you did in the first function and set the pointer in `Picture` to that new instance. You might also want to mark these two functions as `static` if they are not, already.